# Check if a number is divisible by a decimal

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I need to ask the user to input a sequence of numbers and then for each number, do a for loop to determine if it is divisible by `0.2`. Then, if it isn't, put it in another list. Then, print the last number of the second list. If nothing in that list, print "none are a multiple of `0.2`". I will list the code I have so far. Any help would be appreciated!

```
a = input("Enter first decimal number : ")
b = input("Enter second decimal number : ")
c = input("Enter third decimal number : ")
d = input("Enter fourth decimal number : ")
e = input("Enter fifth decimal number : ")

f= type(list)
print(list(a,b,c,d,e))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a for loop to save all input digits in a list:

```
nums = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
l = []

for nth in nums:
    l.append(input("Enter {} decimal number : ".format(nth)))

#Enter first decimal number : 1.2
#Enter second decimal number : 5.2
#Enter third decimal number : 5
#Enter fourth decimal number : 4.2
#Enter fifth decimal number : 3.13
```

The best approach to check whether the digit is divisible by `0.2` is to use the `decimal` module, otherwise floating point errors might make it tricker. You can just start iterating from the last digit using `reversed` and `break` as soon as the first match is found:

```
from decimal import Decimal, InvalidOperation

for number in reversed(l):
    try:
        if (Decimal(number) % Decimal('0.2')) == 0:
            print('The last number divisible by 0.2 is {}'.format(number)) 
            break
    except InvalidOperation:
        pass
else:
    print('No numbers are divisible by 0.2')
```

---

Which prints:

```
The last number divisible by 0.2 is 4.2
```

Answer (score -1):

I would put all the values into a list then loop through

```
isThereMultiple = False
nums = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
for i in list:
    if (float(i)/0.2).is_integer():
        isThereMultiple = True
```

Hope this helps!
(fixed the `1%0.2` bug)

Comment: Fails for `1.0`. And don't use `list` as a variable name!

Comment: Fixed it!! Now I use is_integer() on a division

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.